# Fixing exited docker container

Tags: nginx, docker

I have a nginx container, while I was experimenting with its configuration file, I tried restarting the container to see the effects. But unfortunately due to a typo, container exiting.

Please give me pointers on how to login to that docker to fix the typo and start the container back.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `docker logs` for your exited container please?

Comment: Are you running the container locally or in a container service?

Comment: Build again your modified nginx and relaunch it, and remove the failing one

Comment: Thank you all for the replies, I have added an answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I just did by simply replacing the file using docker cp nginx.conf :/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf and gave docker start